# Azure IoT Device Provisioning Interface Specification

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

Is there an interface specification of the device provisioning API (which is implemented by the Azure IoT C SDK provisioning_client) available and if yes where can I find it?

I would be interested in the URI, required payload and the json response for the MQTT protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference [SDK API Reference Documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c#sdk-api-reference-documentation).

And there are REST APIs for Azure IoT DPS, for example, [Create or update a device enrollment record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/deviceenrollment/createorupdate):

**HTTP request**: PUT https://localhost/enrollments/{id}?api-version=2018-04-01

**Request Body**:

[image]

[image]

**Responses:**

[image]

[image]